# How to configure "Only other Logic Apps" in Logic App ARM template to be called from a specific Logic App only?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

In Azure portal, there's an option to configure Logic App to be called from other Logic Apps only.

[image]

I want to configure this option in ARM template for my Logic App to be triggered from a specific Logic App only.

I can configure "Specific IP ranges" option by adding below to my Logic App ARM template:

```
"accessControl":{
   "triggers":{
      "allowedCallerIpAddresses":[
         {
            "addressRange":"<IPAddress>"
         },
         {
            "addressRange":"<IPAddress>"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So I have tried similar approach for "Only other Logic Apps" but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
"accessControl":{
   "triggers":{
      "allowedCallers":[
         "/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/<CallerLogicApp>"
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not that simple unfortunately.  https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/securing-azure-logic-app-http-triggers-with-azure-ad

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding accessControl to the properties node within the ARM-template. Within the accessControl you should add a trigger node that has the property allowedCallerIpAddresses with the value of an empty array.

Code:

[image]